# Why is $g(c) = 0$ and $g^{(k)}(c) = 0$ for $k < n$ in this proof of Taylor's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

I am reading a proof of Taylor's theorem given in Ross' Elementary Analysis, but I just cant't figure out this one step.

**Definition**: The remainder of the Taylor series for $f$ about $c$ is
$$
R_n(x) = f(x) - \sum\limits^{n-1}_{k=0} \frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!} (x - c)^k
$$

**Theorem**: Let $f$ be defined on $(a, b)$ where $a < c< b$; here we allow $a = -
\infty$ or $b = \infty$. Suppose the nth derivative $f^{(n)}$  exists on $(a, b)$. Then for each $x \neq c$ in $(a,b)$ there is some $y$ between $c$ and $x$ such that
$$
R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n)}(y)}{n!}
(x-c)^n$$

The book gives the following (partial) proof:

Fix $x \neq c$, $n \geq 1$. Let $M$ be the unique solution to
$$
f(x) = \sum\limits^{n-1}_{k=0} \frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!} (x - c)^k + \frac{M(x-c)^n}{n!}
$$
Hence, we need to show $f^{(n)}(y) = M$ for some $y$ between $c$ and $x$. Define
$$
g(t) = \sum\limits^{n-1}_{k=0} \frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!} (t - c)^k + \frac{M(t-c)^n}{n!} - f(t)
$$
A direct calculation shows $g(c) = 0$ and and $g^{(k)}(c) = 0$ for $k < n$. The proof continues from here, but I understand all further steps so I left the rest out.

So, why does a direct calculation show this? We have
$$
g(c) = \sum\limits^{n-1}_{k=0} \frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!} (c - c)^k + \frac{M(c-c)^n}{n!} - f(c) = -f(c)
$$
BUt I can't seem to understand why $f(c) = 0$ as this is not given in the assumptions nor derived earlier? Similarly, for $g^{(m)}(t)$ I understand that the first and second term vanish for $t=c$, but not why $f^{(m)}(c) = 0$ should be true. Thank you for reading this.